# AVCaptureMovieFileOutput.startRecording(to:recordingDelegate:) sometimes hang with no error/exception

Tags: swift, freeze, avcapturesession, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I'm using the AVCaptureSession to record an iPad screen from a macOS device. The recording duration is long and I use `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput.startRecording(to:recordingDelegate:)` to start a new recording depending on a certain condition. (I don't use the `stopRecording()` method unless I want to stop the recording session, this is to make sure there are no lost data between recording files)

Now, it doesn't happen on a consistent pattern, but sometimes the whole app freezes, and when I pause it, I always see that the app stops execution at this method. (specifically at `0x7fff2b6deb22 <+598>:  movq   (%r14,%r12), %rax`)

[image: AVCaptureMovieFileOutput.startRecording(to:recordingDelegate:)]

```
AVFoundation`-[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate:]:
    0x7fff2b6de8cc <+0>:    pushq  %rbp
    0x7fff2b6de8cd <+1>:    movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x7fff2b6de8d0 <+4>:    pushq  %r15
    0x7fff2b6de8d2 <+6>:    pushq  %r14
    0x7fff2b6de8d4 <+8>:    pushq  %r13
    0x7fff2b6de8d6 <+10>:   pushq  %r12
    0x7fff2b6de8d8 <+12>:   pushq  %rbx
    0x7fff2b6de8d9 <+13>:   subq   $0x58, %rsp
    0x7fff2b6de8dd <+17>:   movq   %rsi, %r14
    0x7fff2b6de8e0 <+20>:   movq   %rdi, %r12
    0x7fff2b6de8e3 <+23>:   testq  %rdx, %rdx
    0x7fff2b6de8e6 <+26>:   je     0x7fff2b6dedbb            ; <+1263>
    0x7fff2b6de8ec <+32>:   movq   %rcx, %rbx
    0x7fff2b6de8ef <+35>:   movq   %rdx, %r13
    0x7fff2b6de8f2 <+38>:   movq   0x5b637acf(%rip), %rsi    ; "isFileURL"
    0x7fff2b6de8f9 <+45>:   movq   %rdx, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6de8fc <+48>:   callq  *0x5b5a977e(%rip)         ; (void *)0x00007fff68d3c800: objc_msgSend
    0x7fff2b6de902 <+54>:   testb  %al, %al
    0x7fff2b6de904 <+56>:   je     0x7fff2b6dedd8            ; <+1292>
    0x7fff2b6de90a <+62>:   testq  %rbx, %rbx
    0x7fff2b6de90d <+65>:   je     0x7fff2b6dee38            ; <+1388>
    0x7fff2b6de913 <+71>:   movq   %rbx, -0x30(%rbp)
    0x7fff2b6de917 <+75>:   movq   0x5b639422(%rip), %rsi    ; "_activeConnections"
    0x7fff2b6de91e <+82>:   movq   0x5b5a975b(%rip), %r15    ; (void *)0x00007fff68d3c800: objc_msgSend
    0x7fff2b6de925 <+89>:   movq   %r12, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6de928 <+92>:   callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6de92b <+95>:   movq   0x5b6350ae(%rip), %rsi    ; "count"
    0x7fff2b6de932 <+102>:  movq   %rax, -0x38(%rbp)
    0x7fff2b6de936 <+106>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6de939 <+109>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6de93c <+112>:  testq  %rax, %rax
    0x7fff2b6de93f <+115>:  je     0x7fff2b6dee6c            ; <+1440>
    0x7fff2b6de945 <+121>:  movq   0x5b638594(%rip), %r14    ; "path"
    0x7fff2b6de94c <+128>:  movq   %r13, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6de94f <+131>:  movq   %r14, %rsi
    0x7fff2b6de952 <+134>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6de955 <+137>:  movq   0x5b63941c(%rip), %rsi    ; "stringByStandardizingPath"
    0x7fff2b6de95c <+144>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6de95f <+147>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6de962 <+150>:  movq   %rax, %rbx
    0x7fff2b6de965 <+153>:  movq   0x5b639414(%rip), %rsi    ; "outputFileURL"
    0x7fff2b6de96c <+160>:  movq   %r12, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6de96f <+163>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6de972 <+166>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6de975 <+169>:  movq   %r14, %rsi
    0x7fff2b6de978 <+172>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6de97b <+175>:  movq   0x5b634d8e(%rip), %rsi    ; "isEqualToString:"
    0x7fff2b6de982 <+182>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6de985 <+185>:  movq   %rbx, %rdx
    0x7fff2b6de988 <+188>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6de98b <+191>:  testb  %al, %al
    0x7fff2b6de98d <+193>:  jne    0x7fff2b6dedac            ; <+1248>
    0x7fff2b6de993 <+199>:  testq  %rbx, %rbx
    0x7fff2b6de996 <+202>:  je     0x7fff2b6de9b4            ; <+232>
    0x7fff2b6de998 <+204>:  movq   0x5b63c069(%rip), %rdi    ; (void *)0x00007fff8782c7a8: NSURL
    0x7fff2b6de99f <+211>:  movq   0x5b6393e2(%rip), %rsi    ; "fileURLWithPath:"
    0x7fff2b6de9a6 <+218>:  movq   %rbx, %rdx
    0x7fff2b6de9a9 <+221>:  callq  *0x5b5a96d1(%rip)         ; (void *)0x00007fff68d3c800: objc_msgSend
    0x7fff2b6de9af <+227>:  movq   %rax, %r13
    0x7fff2b6de9b2 <+230>:  jmp    0x7fff2b6de9b7            ; <+235>
    0x7fff2b6de9b4 <+232>:  xorl   %r13d, %r13d
    0x7fff2b6de9b7 <+235>:  movq   %r12, %r14
    0x7fff2b6de9ba <+238>:  movq   $0x0, -0x40(%rbp)
    0x7fff2b6de9c2 <+246>:  movq   0x5b6393a7(%rip), %rsi    ; "_stopError"
    0x7fff2b6de9c9 <+253>:  movq   %r12, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6de9cc <+256>:  callq  *0x5b5a96ae(%rip)         ; (void *)0x00007fff68d3c800: objc_msgSend
    0x7fff2b6de9d2 <+262>:  testq  %rax, %rax
    0x7fff2b6de9d5 <+265>:  je     0x7fff2b6dea1c            ; <+336>
    0x7fff2b6de9d7 <+267>:  movq   0x5b63bfd2(%rip), %rbx    ; (void *)0x00007fff8782c2a8: NSArray
    0x7fff2b6de9de <+274>:  movq   0x5b63c9db(%rip), %rdi    ; (void *)0x00007fff86d27950: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingOperationDescriptor
    0x7fff2b6de9e5 <+281>:  movq   0x5b6393b4(%rip), %rsi    ; "recordingOperationDescriptorWithOutputFileURL:delegate:connections:"
    0x7fff2b6de9ec <+288>:  movq   %r13, %rdx
    0x7fff2b6de9ef <+291>:  movq   -0x30(%rbp), %rcx
    0x7fff2b6de9f3 <+295>:  movq   -0x38(%rbp), %r8
    0x7fff2b6de9f7 <+299>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6de9fa <+302>:  movq   0x5b6355df(%rip), %rsi    ; "arrayWithObject:"
    0x7fff2b6dea01 <+309>:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6dea04 <+312>:  movq   %rax, %rdx
    0x7fff2b6dea07 <+315>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6dea0a <+318>:  movq   0x5b639397(%rip), %rsi    ; "_handleCanceledOperations:"
    0x7fff2b6dea11 <+325>:  movq   %r14, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6dea14 <+328>:  movq   %rax, %rdx
    0x7fff2b6dea17 <+331>:  jmp    0x7fff2b6deda9            ; <+1245>
    0x7fff2b6dea1c <+336>:  movq   0x5b63c4d5(%rip), %rdi    ; (void *)0x00007fff87da2530: NSFileManager
    0x7fff2b6dea23 <+343>:  movq   0x5b637c7e(%rip), %rsi    ; "defaultManager"
    0x7fff2b6dea2a <+350>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6dea2d <+353>:  movq   0x5b63935c(%rip), %rsi    ; "fileExistsAtPath:"
    0x7fff2b6dea34 <+360>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6dea37 <+363>:  movq   %rbx, %rdx
    0x7fff2b6dea3a <+366>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6dea3d <+369>:  testb  %al, %al
    0x7fff2b6dea3f <+371>:  je     0x7fff2b6deabf            ; <+499>
    0x7fff2b6dea41 <+373>:  leaq   0x5b5ad8b8(%rip), %rax    ; AVFoundationErrorDomain
    0x7fff2b6dea48 <+380>:  movq   (%rax), %rdi
    0x7fff2b6dea4b <+383>:  movq   $-0x2e2f, %rsi            ; imm = 0xD1D1 
    0x7fff2b6dea52 <+390>:  xorl   %edx, %edx
    0x7fff2b6dea54 <+392>:  callq  0x7fff2b6b9a08            ; AVLocalizedError
    0x7fff2b6dea59 <+397>:  movq   %r14, %rbx
    0x7fff2b6dea5c <+400>:  movq   0x5b639335(%rip), %r14    ; "_setStopError:"
    0x7fff2b6dea63 <+407>:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6dea66 <+410>:  movq   %r14, %rsi
    0x7fff2b6dea69 <+413>:  movq   %rax, %rdx
    0x7fff2b6dea6c <+416>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6dea6f <+419>:  movq   0x5b63bf3a(%rip), %r12    ; (void *)0x00007fff8782c2a8: NSArray
    0x7fff2b6dea76 <+426>:  movq   0x5b63c943(%rip), %rdi    ; (void *)0x00007fff86d27950: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingOperationDescriptor
    0x7fff2b6dea7d <+433>:  movq   0x5b63931c(%rip), %rsi    ; "recordingOperationDescriptorWithOutputFileURL:delegate:connections:"
    0x7fff2b6dea84 <+440>:  movq   %r13, %rdx
    0x7fff2b6dea87 <+443>:  movq   -0x30(%rbp), %rcx
    0x7fff2b6dea8b <+447>:  movq   -0x38(%rbp), %r8
    0x7fff2b6dea8f <+451>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6dea92 <+454>:  movq   0x5b635547(%rip), %rsi    ; "arrayWithObject:"
    0x7fff2b6dea99 <+461>:  movq   %r12, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6dea9c <+464>:  movq   %rax, %rdx
    0x7fff2b6dea9f <+467>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6deaa2 <+470>:  movq   0x5b6392ff(%rip), %rsi    ; "_handleCanceledOperations:"
    0x7fff2b6deaa9 <+477>:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6deaac <+480>:  movq   %rax, %rdx
    0x7fff2b6deaaf <+483>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6deab2 <+486>:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6deab5 <+489>:  movq   %r14, %rsi
    0x7fff2b6deab8 <+492>:  xorl   %edx, %edx
    0x7fff2b6deaba <+494>:  jmp    0x7fff2b6deda9            ; <+1245>
    0x7fff2b6deabf <+499>:  movq   0x5b6392ea(%rip), %rsi    ; "_noDataConnections"
    0x7fff2b6deac6 <+506>:  movq   %r14, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6deac9 <+509>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6deacc <+512>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6deacf <+515>:  movq   0x5b634f0a(%rip), %rsi    ; "count"
    0x7fff2b6dead6 <+522>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6dead9 <+525>:  testq  %rax, %rax
    0x7fff2b6deadc <+528>:  je     0x7fff2b6dec0b            ; <+831>
    0x7fff2b6deae2 <+534>:  movq   0x5b640a0f(%rip), %r12    ; AVCaptureMovieFileOutput._internal
    0x7fff2b6deae9 <+541>:  movq   %r13, %rbx
    0x7fff2b6deaec <+544>:  movl   $0xf4, %r13d
    0x7fff2b6deaf2 <+550>:  movq   (%r14,%r12), %rdi
    0x7fff2b6deaf6 <+554>:  addq   %r13, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6deaf9 <+557>:  callq  0x7fff2b82d274            ; symbol stub for: os_unfair_lock_lock
    0x7fff2b6deafe <+562>:  movq   (%r14,%r12), %rax
    0x7fff2b6deb02 <+566>:  movb   $0x1, 0xf1(%rax)
    0x7fff2b6deb09 <+573>:  movq   (%r14,%r12), %rdi
    0x7fff2b6deb0d <+577>:  addq   %r13, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6deb10 <+580>:  callq  0x7fff2b82d27a            ; symbol stub for: os_unfair_lock_unlock
    0x7fff2b6deb15 <+585>:  movq   0x5b63929c(%rip), %rsi    ; "_forciblyStopFileWritingForRunningRecordingOperation"
    0x7fff2b6deb1c <+592>:  movq   %r14, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6deb1f <+595>:  callq  *%r15
->  0x7fff2b6deb22 <+598>:  movq   (%r14,%r12), %rax
    0x7fff2b6deb26 <+602>:  movq   0x58(%rax), %rdi
    0x7fff2b6deb2a <+606>:  movq   0x5b63767f(%rip), %rsi    ; "lock"
    0x7fff2b6deb31 <+613>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6deb34 <+616>:  movq   (%r14,%r12), %rax
    0x7fff2b6deb38 <+620>:  movq   0x50(%rax), %rdi
    0x7fff2b6deb3c <+624>:  movq   0x5b63927d(%rip), %rsi    ; "dequeueAllOperationDescriptors"
    0x7fff2b6deb43 <+631>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6deb46 <+634>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6deb49 <+637>:  callq  *0x5b5a9541(%rip)         ; (void *)0x00007fff68d3c6d0: objc_retain
    0x7fff2b6deb4f <+643>:  movq   %rax, -0x40(%rbp)
    0x7fff2b6deb53 <+647>:  testq  %rbx, %rbx
    0x7fff2b6deb56 <+650>:  je     0x7fff2b6debc5            ; <+761>
    0x7fff2b6deb58 <+652>:  movq   (%r14,%r12), %rax
    0x7fff2b6deb5c <+656>:  movq   0x50(%rax), %rax
    0x7fff2b6deb60 <+660>:  movq   %rax, -0x48(%rbp)
    0x7fff2b6deb64 <+664>:  movq   0x5b63c855(%rip), %rdi    ; (void *)0x00007fff86d27950: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingOperationDescriptor
    0x7fff2b6deb6b <+671>:  movq   0x5b63922e(%rip), %rsi    ; "recordingOperationDescriptorWithOutputFileURL:delegate:connections:"
    0x7fff2b6deb72 <+678>:  movq   %rbx, %rdx
    0x7fff2b6deb75 <+681>:  movq   -0x30(%rbp), %rcx
    0x7fff2b6deb79 <+685>:  movq   -0x38(%rbp), %r8
    0x7fff2b6deb7d <+689>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6deb80 <+692>:  movq   %rax, -0x30(%rbp)
    0x7fff2b6deb84 <+696>:  movq   0x5b63923d(%rip), %rdx    ; "_syncTime"
    0x7fff2b6deb8b <+703>:  leaq   -0x78(%rbp), %rbx
    0x7fff2b6deb8f <+707>:  movq   %rbx, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6deb92 <+710>:  movq   %r14, %rsi
    0x7fff2b6deb95 <+713>:  callq  0x7fff2b82d220            ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend_stret
    0x7fff2b6deb9a <+718>:  movq   0x5b63922f(%rip), %rsi    ; "enqueueOperationDescriptor:forTime:dequeuedOperationDescriptors:"
    0x7fff2b6deba1 <+725>:  subq   $0x8, %rsp
    0x7fff2b6deba5 <+729>:  movq   0x10(%rbx), %rax
    0x7fff2b6deba9 <+733>:  movq   (%rbx), %r8
    0x7fff2b6debac <+736>:  movq   0x8(%rbx), %rbx
    0x7fff2b6debb0 <+740>:  movq   -0x48(%rbp), %rdi
    0x7fff2b6debb4 <+744>:  movq   -0x30(%rbp), %rdx
    0x7fff2b6debb8 <+748>:  xorl   %ecx, %ecx
    0x7fff2b6debba <+750>:  pushq  %rax
    0x7fff2b6debbb <+751>:  pushq  %rbx
    0x7fff2b6debbc <+752>:  pushq  %r8
    0x7fff2b6debbe <+754>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6debc1 <+757>:  addq   $0x20, %rsp
    0x7fff2b6debc5 <+761>:  movq   (%r14,%r12), %rax
    0x7fff2b6debc9 <+765>:  movq   0x58(%rax), %rdi
    0x7fff2b6debcd <+769>:  movq   0x5b6375ec(%rip), %rsi    ; "unlock"
    0x7fff2b6debd4 <+776>:  callq  *0x5b5a94a6(%rip)         ; (void *)0x00007fff68d3c800: objc_msgSend
    0x7fff2b6debda <+782>:  movq   -0x40(%rbp), %rdi
    0x7fff2b6debde <+786>:  callq  0x7fff2b82d1ba            ; symbol stub for: objc_autorelease
    0x7fff2b6debe3 <+791>:  movq   (%r14,%r12), %rdi
    0x7fff2b6debe7 <+795>:  addq   %r13, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6debea <+798>:  callq  0x7fff2b82d274            ; symbol stub for: os_unfair_lock_lock
    0x7fff2b6debef <+803>:  movq   (%r14,%r12), %rax
    0x7fff2b6debf3 <+807>:  movb   $0x0, 0xf1(%rax)
    0x7fff2b6debfa <+814>:  addq   (%r14,%r12), %r13
    0x7fff2b6debfe <+818>:  movq   %r13, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6dec01 <+821>:  callq  0x7fff2b82d27a            ; symbol stub for: os_unfair_lock_unlock
    0x7fff2b6dec06 <+826>:  jmp    0x7fff2b6ded61            ; <+1173>
    0x7fff2b6dec0b <+831>:  movq   0x5b63c2ee(%rip), %rdi    ; (void *)0x00007fff87da42e0: NSThread
    0x7fff2b6dec12 <+838>:  movq   0x5b637a9f(%rip), %rsi    ; "currentThread"
    0x7fff2b6dec19 <+845>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6dec1c <+848>:  movq   0x5b638375(%rip), %rsi    ; "threadDictionary"
    0x7fff2b6dec23 <+855>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6dec26 <+858>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6dec29 <+861>:  movq   0x5b634c00(%rip), %rsi    ; "objectForKey:"
    0x7fff2b6dec30 <+868>:  leaq   0x5b5bfd31(%rip), %rdx    ; @"com.apple.avfoundation.__AVCaptureMovieFileOutputIsCallbackThread"
    0x7fff2b6dec37 <+875>:  movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6dec3a <+878>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6dec3d <+881>:  movq   %rax, %rbx
    0x7fff2b6dec40 <+884>:  movq   0x5b6408b1(%rip), %r12    ; AVCaptureMovieFileOutput._internal
    0x7fff2b6dec47 <+891>:  movq   (%r14,%r12), %rax
    0x7fff2b6dec4b <+895>:  movq   0x58(%rax), %rdi
    0x7fff2b6dec4f <+899>:  movq   0x5b63755a(%rip), %rsi    ; "lock"
    0x7fff2b6dec56 <+906>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6dec59 <+909>:  movq   (%r14,%r12), %rax
    0x7fff2b6dec5d <+913>:  movq   0x50(%rax), %r12
    0x7fff2b6dec61 <+917>:  movq   0x5b63c758(%rip), %rdi    ; (void *)0x00007fff86d27950: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingOperationDescriptor
    0x7fff2b6dec68 <+924>:  movq   0x5b639131(%rip), %rsi    ; "recordingOperationDescriptorWithOutputFileURL:delegate:connections:"
    0x7fff2b6dec6f <+931>:  movq   %r13, %rdx
    0x7fff2b6dec72 <+934>:  movq   -0x30(%rbp), %rcx
    0x7fff2b6dec76 <+938>:  movq   -0x38(%rbp), %r8
    0x7fff2b6dec7a <+942>:  callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6dec7d <+945>:  movq   %rax, %rdx
    0x7fff2b6dec80 <+948>:  testq  %rbx, %rbx
    0x7fff2b6dec83 <+951>:  movq   %rbx, -0x48(%rbp)
    0x7fff2b6dec87 <+955>:  movq   %r12, %r13
    0x7fff2b6dec8a <+958>:  je     0x7fff2b6decac            ; <+992>
    0x7fff2b6dec8c <+960>:  movq   0x5b5a63ad(%rip), %rax    ; (void *)0x00007fff310fae28: kCMTimeNegativeInfinity
    0x7fff2b6dec93 <+967>:  movq   0x10(%rax), %rcx
    0x7fff2b6dec97 <+971>:  movq   %rcx, -0x50(%rbp)
    0x7fff2b6dec9b <+975>:  movq   (%rax), %rcx
    0x7fff2b6dec9e <+978>:  movq   0x8(%rax), %rax
    0x7fff2b6deca2 <+982>:  movq   %rax, -0x58(%rbp)
    0x7fff2b6deca6 <+986>:  movq   %rcx, -0x60(%rbp)
    0x7fff2b6decaa <+990>:  jmp    0x7fff2b6decc5            ; <+1017>
    0x7fff2b6decac <+992>:  movq   %rdx, %rbx
    0x7fff2b6decaf <+995>:  movq   0x5b639112(%rip), %rdx    ; "_syncTime"
    0x7fff2b6decb6 <+1002>: leaq   -0x60(%rbp), %rdi
    0x7fff2b6decba <+1006>: movq   %r14, %rsi
    0x7fff2b6decbd <+1009>: callq  0x7fff2b82d220            ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend_stret
    0x7fff2b6decc2 <+1014>: movq   %rbx, %rdx
    0x7fff2b6decc5 <+1017>: movq   0x5b639104(%rip), %rsi    ; "enqueueOperationDescriptor:forTime:dequeuedOperationDescriptors:"
    0x7fff2b6deccc <+1024>: subq   $0x8, %rsp
    0x7fff2b6decd0 <+1028>: movq   -0x50(%rbp), %rax
    0x7fff2b6decd4 <+1032>: movq   -0x60(%rbp), %r8
    0x7fff2b6decd8 <+1036>: movq   -0x58(%rbp), %rbx
    0x7fff2b6decdc <+1040>: leaq   -0x40(%rbp), %r12
    0x7fff2b6dece0 <+1044>: movq   %r13, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6dece3 <+1047>: movq   %r12, %rcx
    0x7fff2b6dece6 <+1050>: pushq  %rax
    0x7fff2b6dece7 <+1051>: pushq  %rbx
    0x7fff2b6dece8 <+1052>: pushq  %r8
    0x7fff2b6decea <+1054>: callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6deced <+1057>: addq   $0x20, %rsp
    0x7fff2b6decf1 <+1061>: movq   (%r12), %rdi
    0x7fff2b6decf5 <+1065>: callq  *0x5b5a9395(%rip)         ; (void *)0x00007fff68d3c6d0: objc_retain
    0x7fff2b6decfb <+1071>: movq   0x5b6407f6(%rip), %rax    ; AVCaptureMovieFileOutput._internal
    0x7fff2b6ded02 <+1078>: movq   (%r14,%rax), %rax
    0x7fff2b6ded06 <+1082>: movq   0x58(%rax), %rdi
    0x7fff2b6ded0a <+1086>: movq   0x5b6374af(%rip), %rsi    ; "unlock"
    0x7fff2b6ded11 <+1093>: callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6ded14 <+1096>: movq   (%r12), %rdi
    0x7fff2b6ded18 <+1100>: callq  0x7fff2b82d1ba            ; symbol stub for: objc_autorelease
    0x7fff2b6ded1d <+1105>: cmpq   $0x0, -0x48(%rbp)
    0x7fff2b6ded22 <+1110>: jne    0x7fff2b6ded61            ; <+1173>
    0x7fff2b6ded24 <+1112>: movq   0x5b6390ad(%rip), %rbx    ; "_startFileControlCallbackTimeoutTimer"
    0x7fff2b6ded2b <+1119>: movq   0x5b63bc7e(%rip), %rdi    ; (void *)0x00007fff8782c2a8: NSArray
    0x7fff2b6ded32 <+1126>: movq   0x5b5a6047(%rip), %rax    ; (void *)0x00007fff876fb4a8: kCFRunLoopCommonModes
    0x7fff2b6ded39 <+1133>: movq   (%rax), %rdx
    0x7fff2b6ded3c <+1136>: movq   0x5b63529d(%rip), %rsi    ; "arrayWithObject:"
    0x7fff2b6ded43 <+1143>: callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6ded46 <+1146>: movq   0x5b639093(%rip), %rsi    ; "performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:"
    0x7fff2b6ded4d <+1153>: movq   %r14, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6ded50 <+1156>: movq   %rbx, %rdx
    0x7fff2b6ded53 <+1159>: xorl   %ecx, %ecx
    0x7fff2b6ded55 <+1161>: movl   $0x1, %r8d
    0x7fff2b6ded5b <+1167>: movq   %rax, %r9
    0x7fff2b6ded5e <+1170>: callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6ded61 <+1173>: movq   0x5b639080(%rip), %rbx    ; "_refreshRecordingState"
    0x7fff2b6ded68 <+1180>: movq   0x5b63bc41(%rip), %rdi    ; (void *)0x00007fff8782c2a8: NSArray
    0x7fff2b6ded6f <+1187>: movq   0x5b5a600a(%rip), %rax    ; (void *)0x00007fff876fb4a8: kCFRunLoopCommonModes
    0x7fff2b6ded76 <+1194>: movq   (%rax), %rdx
    0x7fff2b6ded79 <+1197>: movq   0x5b635260(%rip), %rsi    ; "arrayWithObject:"
    0x7fff2b6ded80 <+1204>: callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6ded83 <+1207>: movq   0x5b639056(%rip), %rsi    ; "performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:"
    0x7fff2b6ded8a <+1214>: movq   %r14, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6ded8d <+1217>: movq   %rbx, %rdx
    0x7fff2b6ded90 <+1220>: xorl   %ecx, %ecx
    0x7fff2b6ded92 <+1222>: xorl   %r8d, %r8d
    0x7fff2b6ded95 <+1225>: movq   %rax, %r9
    0x7fff2b6ded98 <+1228>: callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6ded9b <+1231>: movq   -0x40(%rbp), %rdx
    0x7fff2b6ded9f <+1235>: movq   0x5b639002(%rip), %rsi    ; "_handleCanceledOperations:"
    0x7fff2b6deda6 <+1242>: movq   %r14, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6deda9 <+1245>: callq  *%r15
    0x7fff2b6dedac <+1248>: addq   $0x58, %rsp
    0x7fff2b6dedb0 <+1252>: popq   %rbx
    0x7fff2b6dedb1 <+1253>: popq   %r12
    0x7fff2b6dedb3 <+1255>: popq   %r13
    0x7fff2b6dedb5 <+1257>: popq   %r14
    0x7fff2b6dedb7 <+1259>: popq   %r15
    0x7fff2b6dedb9 <+1261>: popq   %rbp
    0x7fff2b6dedba <+1262>: retq   
    0x7fff2b6dedbb <+1263>: movq   %r12, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6dedbe <+1266>: movq   0x5b63bb9b(%rip), %rbx    ; (void *)0x00007fff8782c438: NSException
    0x7fff2b6dedc5 <+1273>: movq   0x5b5a5e74(%rip), %rax    ; (void *)0x00007fff87730640: NSInvalidArgumentException
    0x7fff2b6dedcc <+1280>: movq   (%rax), %r12
    0x7fff2b6dedcf <+1283>: leaq   0x5b5bd4f2(%rip), %rdx    ; @"Nil URL passed"
    0x7fff2b6dedd6 <+1290>: jmp    0x7fff2b6dee53            ; <+1415>
    0x7fff2b6dedd8 <+1292>: movq   0x5b63bb81(%rip), %rbx    ; (void *)0x00007fff8782c438: NSException
    0x7fff2b6deddf <+1299>: movq   0x5b5a5e5a(%rip), %rax    ; (void *)0x00007fff87730640: NSInvalidArgumentException
    0x7fff2b6dede6 <+1306>: movq   (%rax), %r15
    0x7fff2b6dede9 <+1309>: movq   0x5b63bb20(%rip), %rdi    ; (void *)0x00007fff87da4178: NSString
    0x7fff2b6dedf0 <+1316>: movq   0x5b6348d1(%rip), %rsi    ; "stringWithFormat:"
    0x7fff2b6dedf7 <+1323>: leaq   0x5b5bd4ea(%rip), %rdx    ; @"Cannot record to URL %@ because it is not a file URL"
    0x7fff2b6dedfe <+1330>: movq   0x5b5a927b(%rip), %r8     ; (void *)0x00007fff68d3c800: objc_msgSend
    0x7fff2b6dee05 <+1337>: movq   %r13, %rcx
    0x7fff2b6dee08 <+1340>: xorl   %eax, %eax
    0x7fff2b6dee0a <+1342>: movq   %r8, %r13
    0x7fff2b6dee0d <+1345>: callq  *%r8
    0x7fff2b6dee10 <+1348>: movq   %r12, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6dee13 <+1351>: movq   %r14, %rsi
    0x7fff2b6dee16 <+1354>: movq   %rax, %rdx
    0x7fff2b6dee19 <+1357>: xorl   %eax, %eax
    0x7fff2b6dee1b <+1359>: callq  0x7fff2b79f3ca            ; AVMethodExceptionReasonWithObjectAndSelector
    0x7fff2b6dee20 <+1364>: movq   0x5b634b71(%rip), %rsi    ; "exceptionWithName:reason:userInfo:"
    0x7fff2b6dee27 <+1371>: movq   %rbx, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6dee2a <+1374>: movq   %r15, %rdx
    0x7fff2b6dee2d <+1377>: movq   %rax, %rcx
    0x7fff2b6dee30 <+1380>: xorl   %r8d, %r8d
    0x7fff2b6dee33 <+1383>: callq  *%r13
    0x7fff2b6dee36 <+1386>: jmp    0x7fff2b6deeaa            ; <+1502>
    0x7fff2b6dee38 <+1388>: movq   %r12, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6dee3b <+1391>: movq   0x5b63bb1e(%rip), %rbx    ; (void *)0x00007fff8782c438: NSException
    0x7fff2b6dee42 <+1398>: movq   0x5b5a5df7(%rip), %rax    ; (void *)0x00007fff87730640: NSInvalidArgumentException
    0x7fff2b6dee49 <+1405>: movq   (%rax), %r12
    0x7fff2b6dee4c <+1408>: leaq   0x5b5bd4b5(%rip), %rdx    ; @"Nil delegate passed"
    0x7fff2b6dee53 <+1415>: movq   %r14, %rsi
    0x7fff2b6dee56 <+1418>: xorl   %eax, %eax
    0x7fff2b6dee58 <+1420>: callq  0x7fff2b79f3ca            ; AVMethodExceptionReasonWithObjectAndSelector
    0x7fff2b6dee5d <+1425>: movq   0x5b634b34(%rip), %rsi    ; "exceptionWithName:reason:userInfo:"
    0x7fff2b6dee64 <+1432>: movq   %rbx, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6dee67 <+1435>: movq   %r12, %rdx
    0x7fff2b6dee6a <+1438>: jmp    0x7fff2b6dee9e            ; <+1490>
    0x7fff2b6dee6c <+1440>: movq   0x5b63baed(%rip), %rbx    ; (void *)0x00007fff8782c438: NSException
    0x7fff2b6dee73 <+1447>: movq   0x5b5a5dc6(%rip), %rax    ; (void *)0x00007fff87730640: NSInvalidArgumentException
    0x7fff2b6dee7a <+1454>: movq   (%rax), %r15
    0x7fff2b6dee7d <+1457>: leaq   0x5b5bd4a4(%rip), %rdx    ; @"No active/enabled connections"
    0x7fff2b6dee84 <+1464>: movq   %r12, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6dee87 <+1467>: movq   %r14, %rsi
    0x7fff2b6dee8a <+1470>: xorl   %eax, %eax
    0x7fff2b6dee8c <+1472>: callq  0x7fff2b79f3ca            ; AVMethodExceptionReasonWithObjectAndSelector
    0x7fff2b6dee91 <+1477>: movq   0x5b634b00(%rip), %rsi    ; "exceptionWithName:reason:userInfo:"
    0x7fff2b6dee98 <+1484>: movq   %rbx, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6dee9b <+1487>: movq   %r15, %rdx
    0x7fff2b6dee9e <+1490>: movq   %rax, %rcx
    0x7fff2b6deea1 <+1493>: xorl   %r8d, %r8d
    0x7fff2b6deea4 <+1496>: callq  *0x5b5a91d6(%rip)         ; (void *)0x00007fff68d3c800: objc_msgSend
    0x7fff2b6deeaa <+1502>: movq   %rax, %rdi
    0x7fff2b6deead <+1505>: callq  0x7fff2b82d1fc            ; symbol stub for: objc_exception_throw
```

What can I do now with this information, and what possible ways I could prevent this from happening? Are there other things I need to put this into context?

The `startRecording` method is being called in the `captureOutput` delegate, like so:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    // other logic
    if self.shouldStartANewRecording(output, sampleBuffer) {
        self.isRecording = true
        self.lastRecordedAt = Date()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(20)) {
            self.movieFileOutput.startRecording(to: fileName, recordingDelegate: self) // here
        }
    } else if self.shouldStopRecording() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(20)) {
            self.movieFileOutput.stopRecording()
            self.isRecording = false
        }
    }
    // other logic
}
```

Comment: I believe you are experiencing some sort of deadlock, perhaps due to overlapping recording sessions. The fact that you never `stopRecording` would tend to confirm that notion.

Comment: @matt But in the docs it says `In macOS, you don’t need to call stopRecording() before calling this method while another recording is in progress. If you call this method while the output object is recording, the framework preserves media samples between the old file and the new file.` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturefileoutput/1387224-startrecording

Comment: Ok but you have to admit the async jump of 20 seconds is odd. I don’t know what happens to your buffer during that, and your Bool flag is subject to corruption. It’s just a guess, but sigstop is usually a threading issue, usually deadlock. Did you turn on the thread sanitizer? It might have some advice perhaps...